# Text To Speech functionality when app is in background mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, text-to-speech, background-mode

I am working on a `TextToSpeech` app. I write one paragraph in a `UITextField`, then I press the **Speak** button. Sound plays according to the text written in the `UITextField`.

[image]

However, when the app is in background mode, the audio stops playing. How can I continue to play the sound in background mode? Similar to how an audio player can play a song in the background.

I am using the following code for text to speech:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Google_TTS_BySham.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic,strong)Google_TTS_BySham *google_TTS_BySham;
@property (nonatomic,strong)IBOutlet UITextField *txtString;

@end

@implementation ViewController

#pragma mark - View Life Cycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - Button Tapped event

- (IBAction)btnSpeakTapped:(id)sender{
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_txtString.text];
    self.google_TTS_BySham = [[Google_TTS_BySham alloc] init];
    [self.google_TTS_BySham speak:str];
}
```

Comment: And code of to play sound is??

Comment: It is library of Google_TTS

Comment: Check your  application  info.plist file and set property Application does not run in background.

Comment: In my application info.plist file i added the following: Application does not run in background : NO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following code in `info.plist` file...

**Application does not run in background : NO**

**Required background modes : App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay**

and then add the following code in `AppDelegate.m` file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

    UInt32 size = sizeof(CFStringRef);
    CFStringRef route;
    AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute, &size, &route);
    NSLog(@"route = %@", route);

    return YES;
}

- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)theEvent {

    if (theEvent.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl)  {
        switch(theEvent.subtype)        {
            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay:
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TogglePlayPause" object:nil];
                break;
            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause:
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TogglePlayPause" object:nil];
                break;
            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlStop:
                break;
            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TogglePlayPause" object:nil];
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how does that even work without playing any music file. your code is pretty much missing and if that even make sense for TTS at all?

Answer (score 1):

Add "App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay" under "Required background modes" property on your info.plist

Hope this will help...

Comment: I add "App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay" and "App provides Voice over IP services" under "Required background modes" property on my info.plist...It is work properly in simulator but not in real ios device

Comment: @AhmetAkkök Yes...It is working properly in real device.

Comment: @Jagat Dave Thank you, I understand that you have already provided the accepted answer here, appreciated 