# Stop speech when app enter foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, text-to-speech

My app stops speaking when enter background and continues speech when entering foreground. I need to stop Speaking when app enters again foreground.

Comment: this link could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28317036/text-to-speech-functionality-when-app-is-in-background-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement this delegate method if code is global

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application 
{
  /// stop speech

}
```

or listen to it in your viewController if it's not

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appWillEnterForeground:) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
```

//

```
 -(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(NSNotification *)paramNotification
{



}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. But not working. i used like-  
   (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
        [speechSynthesizer stopSpeakingAtBoundary:AVSpeechBoundaryImmediate];
    
}

Comment: Not music. Text to Speech and i Use AVSpeechSynthesizer & AVSpeechUtterance. It stops speech when the app enter background but continues speech when entering foreground. I need to stop the speech when entering foreground.

Comment: try this  - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application

Comment: I dont need to play audio (Speech) in background. When the app enter background it stops the speech as desired. But when coming to foreground it resumes the Speech. And i need to stop the speech when entering foreground.

Comment: I got it:  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appWillEnterForeground:) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];    // Really thank you for your help.

Comment: you can use it or execute code in appdelegate if it's global